# Android : How to show DatePicker in onClick EditText - without editable

Tags: android

In my application I'am just calling `DatePicker` when i click the `EditText`.

But when I test this, first it ask us to edit and if I again click that then it will show the `DatePicker`.

I want to show only DatePicker without editable.

Comment: refer this url it will may be help you:  http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1718936/

Comment: use textView if you want to do this.

Comment: @userX I did not ask about how to call the DatePicker. Already I have done that.

Answer (score 1):

put this 2 lines in your edittext xml code

```
 android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener =
                   new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;

        ArrivalDate = new Date(year - 1900, month, day);

        textArrivalDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                    .append("/").append(day).append("/").append(year)
                    .append(""));
    }
};
```

Use the following code block with on TextView Click event:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener,
                    c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
datePickerDialog.SetTitle("Select date");
datePickerDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this. by adding these lines to edittext

```
android:inputType="none"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="false"
```

and in onclick do wat u want.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an `EditText` then.

An `EditText` is meant to let the user input text using a keyboard...

Use a clickable `TextView`, or a kind of `Button` instead.

Answer (score 0):

simplest way to do this use setOnFocusChangeListener instead of OnCLickListner following code is an example which i am using for same purpose.

```
editText_dob.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
            hideSoftKeyboard(RegisterationActivity.this);
            editText_dob.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            setDate(editText_dob);
        }
    }
});
```